# Bold caption in of table

Tags: tables, bold

How to make bold the TABLE: ?

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}%to generate dummy data
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}  
\usepackage{caption} 
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textbf {TABLE}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption[]{Electronic \v{r}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cr}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
a&a\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and nothing has happend. It is not bold.

Comment: `\textbf` takes an argument. You need braces: `\textbf{TABLE}`. That or `\bfseries TABLE`.

Comment: You shouldn't normally put the formatting in such a command. If you want to change it in a caption use e.g. the caption package - but without complete example this is only guessing (and the title of your question is bewildering anyway)

Comment: I editted my question

Comment: Your font has no bold version, you could only fake it.

Comment: OK, thank you and is it possible to write it with different color?

Comment: Loas `xcolor` and type something like 
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textcolor{red}{TABLE}}`.

Comment: Is it possible for number of table too? Thank you

Comment: Yes, see details in the `caption` documentation. You can define your own format with `\DeclareCaptionFormat` and `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` (§4, Own Enhancements).

Comment: How please, `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\textcolor{red}\arabic{Table}}` is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}%to generate dummy data
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}%
  [BoldFont=Segoe UI Bold]  
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption[]{Electronic \v{r}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cr}
    \hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    a&a\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If I use `\setmainfont{Segoe UI}`  instead of the Symbol font I get the following output:

[image]

The symbol font has no `\v{r}`

Comment: Thank you for your solution